# Adding a Bot to Circuit Spaces - "Cannot be added"

Tags: circuit-sdk

When I try to add a Bot to Circuit Spaces I get this message. Is this feature not enabled yet? If it is what do I need to do to add it? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Today it is only possible to add 'persons' to a space if they have the SPACES permission. I assume your bot is missing this permission. The info icon should give a hint why the bot cannot be added.

We did plan to add this in a later step but due to the decomission of Circuit new features are not added anymore. What you could do is to contact your tenant administrator to ask the Circuit DevOps Team to add this permission manually to your bot, but we did not test this functionality so I would suggest to start with a sandbox evaluation first.

Comment: I see, thanks Michael. I assume that one is different from the client scopes? The Bot has READ_SPACE WRITE_SPACE only at the moment. The info icon is non-interactive, nothing happens if I click on it. I'll check with the tenant, but on the sandbox although I have the scope permissions (you helped me with that before) I don't see the spaces icon, I tried "Ctrl+Alt+Shift+B" while on the Circuit Labs tab like I did a long time ago on the Prod version to bring it up when it was pre-released, but no luck.